# find the rank of an element in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the task to combine two vectors in the following way. The input are two vectors with the first one indicating the indices of the dividors of the groups and the second one indicating the elements we are trying to classify. For example, vector [1,3,5,9] means the first group consists of 1, the second group consists of 2 and 3, the third group consists of 4 and 5, and the forth one consists of 6, 7, 8 and 9, etc. In this case, if the second vector is [2,4,6], then the output we get is [2,3,4].
I know how to impliment this in matlab with for loops. My question is: is there anyway to do it without for loops? Many thanks for your time and attentions.

EDIT:

```
scaleVtr=[1,3,5,9];
>> eltVtr=[2,4,6];
>> j=1; output=[];
>> for i=1:size(eltVtr,2)
      while(true)
        if eltVtr(i)<=scaleVtr(j)
           output= [output,j];
           break;
        else j=j+1;
        end
      end
   end
>> output

output =

     2     3     4
```

Comment: Post your loop code with your toy example. Also post the code to generate the toy example data as well.

Comment: @krisdestruction, this is a toy example. The main task is I have a number of sequences, each has certain multiplicity. I need to generate a random sample of it considering the multiplicity. So, with putting all the sequences together group by group(the same sequence forms a group) and one by one, I use the randomsample function to generate the indices of the sequences, in the toy example, it would be 2, 4 and 6. Then, I need to go back to determine the group index. That is what is going on here.

Comment: The pattern is quite complex without stepping through the code, perhaps I'll see it if you post a longer vector? I have the loop version running and can reproduce your output.

Comment: I think this is a common operation. Maybe the matlab team can add a function to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qq = [1 3 5 9]; 
qq2 = [2 4 6];
ceil(interp1(qq,1:numel(qq),qq2))
```

Comment: oh lol if it's that simple, I get what he was trying to do now

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
v1 = [1,3,5,9];
v2 = [2,4,6];
result = sum(bsxfun(@gt, v2(:).', v1(:)), 1) + 1;
```